# AWS EKS ingress - Entity too large

Tags: laravel-8, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I am running Laravel 8 api in the cluster and I have this ingress:

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{"alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme":"internet-facing","alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type":"ip","kubernetes.io/ingress.class":"alb"},"labels":{"app":"voterapi"},"name":"rapp-ingress","namespace":"voterapp"},"spec":{"rules":[{"http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"serviceName":"app-service","servicePort":80},"path":"/*"}]}}]}}
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 100m
  creationTimestamp: "2022-05-26T08:25:50Z"
  finalizers:
  - ingress.k8s.aws/resources
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app: appapi
  name: app-ingress
  namespace: app
  resourceVersion: "94262558"
  uid: ec29661a-f4be-4ae1-a0e0-29c3d8bff0e5
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: app-service
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - hostname: XXX
```

I am trying to upload the file using the API and I am getting

```
413 Request Entity Too Large
```

I dont see this error in my PHP log so looks like it is not even getting there.

Can anyone help me to solve the issue?

Comment: How big is your file?

Comment: @ℛɑƒæĿᴿᴹᴿ it is about 20 MB. Looks like I am not able to upload any file larger than 2 MB

Comment: How is upload_max_filesize in php.ini file?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Try to update your ingress adding `nginx.org/client-max-body-size`

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.org/proxy-read-timeout: "40s"
    nginx.org/proxy-connect-timeout: "40s"
    nginx.org/client-max-body-size: "100m"
```

In some cases, you might need to increase the max size for all post body data and file uploads.

Try to update the `post_max_size` and `upload_max_file_size` values in the `php.ini` configuration:

```
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
```

##### Reference:

- [NGINX Ingress Controller to increase the client request body](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-configure-nginx-ingress-controller/)
- [NGINX Ingress Controller: Advanced Configuration with Annotations](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/advanced-configuration-with-annotations/)
- https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/increase-file-upload-size

Comment: Already did that. Looks like my request not even coming to my back-end laravel  and fails on ingress.